# Add an object with elements to an array

Tags: c#, arrays

since i'm still in a learning progress of c# i'm stuck at a part where i'm trying to add a class object with instance variables into an array of objects.

explenation : 
I got a class 'X' where I got an instance variable of an array with objects of class 'Y'

```
class X
{
    //Instance Variables
    public Y[] objects = new Y[5];

    //Methods
    public void AddObject(Y objectname)
    {
        objects[0] = objectname;
    }
 }
```

When I debug I see 'objectname' gets filled correctly with the arguments
but the array 'objects' is empty with 5 'null' values

Comment: Your code works fine if I do this: `X x = new X(); x.AddObject(new Y());`. How do you call this method?

Comment: "*When I debug I see*" - but where have you set your breakpoint? If just on `objects[0] = objectname;` line - then `objects` should be unmodified yet and you need one more debugging step for this code to be executed.

Comment: Andy... You're right on it... Thanks. The problem was my override toString while I was looking at the wrong code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That shouldn't even compile.

You have to use

```
objects[0] = objectname;
```

instead of

```
Y[0] = objectname;
```

Hint: Take a Look at the [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Comment: Frankly, this: `Y[0] = objectname;` could be compiled if `Y` class  has some indexer like `public Y this[long index]`. But I really doubt it happens in OP code.

Comment: That would mean the type has a static indexer. (Is that even possible?) @AndyKorneyev

Comment: @PatrickHofman I have tried that, it is not. Wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: @PatrickHofman well, technically it is possible. `class Y
    {
        private Y[] _Items = new Y[10];

        public Y this[int index]
        {
            get { return _Items[index]; }
            set { _Items[index] = value; }
        }
    }`

Comment: @AndyKorneyev: No, `this[]` isn't static, so you can't do `Y[]`.

Comment: I misstyped, I do actually use objects[0] = objectname but that doesn't work

Comment: @PatrickHofman oh, my fault. Missed your point about **static** indexer. Need more coffee.... ;)